# Conditional combinations and permutations to identify sequences and patterns in R

Tags: r, combinatorics

I want to identify repeated behavioural patterns in a trader's account. The trader will typically transfer funds into his account denominated in a particular asset, buy and sell different assets, then (not necessarily) transfer out the asset, which can be a different asset than the one transferred into the account.

I want to create conditional combinations and permutations to identify if a trader is repeating a particular pattern.

Assume we have the following:

```
Transfer <- ["In", "Out"]
Action <- ["Buy", "Sell"]
Assets <- ["A", "B", "C"]
```

Expressing operations as combinations of the above lists, a trader can **In_A Sell_A Buy_B Out_B**. A longer sequence is **In_B Sell_B Buy_A Sell_A Buy_C Sell_C Buy_B**.

It is not necessary that there is an In or Out operation. So in a given day a trader might just **Sell_B Buy_A Sell_A Buy_C Sell_C Buy_B** and repeat this operation indefinitely.

The trader cannot buy and sell the same asset **Sell_A Buy_A** since it does not make sense to do so.

Is there a particular method or module that I can look at to create these different conditional combinations in R. I understand the basic combination and permutation functions, but I would appreciate any guidance on applying this in a real-world context as described above.